# Find $g'(\pi)$ where $g(t) = f(F(t))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

> If $f(x,y,z) = \sin x$ and $F(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, t)$, find $g'(\pi)$ where $g(t) = f(F(t))$.

First, I compute $$\begin{align}
g(t) &= f(F(t)) \\ 
&=f(\cos t, \sin t, t) \\
&= \sin(\cos t)
\end{align}$$

Then I find $g'(t) = \cos(\cos t) \cdot (-\sin t)$, but I think I am doing something wrong here and could use some help being pointed in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong from what you did and it follows from it that $g'(\pi)=0$. Of course, you could also have applied the chain rule to $f$ and $F$, but you don't *have* to do that.